# DD-WRT determine router model

Tags: router

I can see the model of my device on the web interface (TPLINK TL-WDR3600 v1), but it's seemingly not available via SNMP.

Is there a way to retrieve this via the command line (SSH)?

FYI - I write software to enumerate the devices on your network, hence the question. I know what "my" router is, but I want to be able to query a router and determine "it's" model...

SNMP would be great but I'll take SSH if I have to :-)

I can see what I assume is the www code at /etc/www (as below) but I can't determine 'how' it's retrieving the model (other than it looks like some perl function)...

```
<% get_sysmodel(); %>
```

Comment: I don't have access to DD-WRT APs as I prefer openwrt, but at least on openwrt /proc/cmdline begins with `board=modelname`, e.g. `board=WNDR3700`, `board=TL-WDR4300`.

Comment: Unfortunately, no...

root@DD-WRT:~# cat /proc/cmdline
console=ttyS0,115200 root=1f02 rootfstype=squashfs noinitrd init=/sbin/init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own post so anyone else looking for this may get an answer...

At the shell run

```
nvram get DD_BOARD
```

and you can also run the following to get a list of all values

```
nvram show
```